How to configure a Postgresql database to store any language strings, while maintaing sorting?
I have a Postgresql database in which all string fields are stored in TEXT columns. Until now, all strings were in the english language, so all BE functionality (sorting, storing, querying, etc.) was correctly functioning in english.
However, I would like to ensure any string, in, if possible, any language, is stored in those same tables, with no modifications to them. All information will be related to users who use those languages, so I don't have to worry about a chinese user seeing any records written in arabic, because they will not be accessible to any other user, but I do care about both users being able to sort their information in their own respective character sets (so, arabic text is still sorted within the arabic language logic, etc.)
Is the fact that the encoding is set to UTF8 enough to ensure all unicode characters are stored properly? Does this also ensure all sorting operations will be correct, in any languages, assuming any user can only see records in the same language?
I see in Postgresql documentation that I should be aware of my LC_TYPE and LC_COLLATE values, to see which character sets my database supports. When I do \l in the postgres terminal, I see the encoding is set to UTF8, and both the Collate and Ctype are set to English_United States.1252. Is there any other configuration which would be relevant to check to ensure proper sorting, filtering and querying?

Does this also ensure all sorting operations will be correct, in any languages, NO. You need to read Collation. This is going to be more involved then you think.

"Does this also ensure all sorting operations will be correct" - no, the database cannot know the language from just the (characters used in the) text and apply language-specific rules based on that. You'll need to tell it explicitly which collation to use for sorting.

Sorting is a question of collation, not of encoding. A PostgreSQL collation must belong to a certain encoding, with the exception of Windows. That exception exists because of Windows' limited support for the UTF-8 encoding and the PostgreSQL developers' limited understanding how Windows works in this area (see this discussion).
While encoding is a fairly simple question (you just use UTF8 as database encoding, then you can store all characters), collation is difficult. There is no sorting order that all languages agree on. You have to find one that works "good enough" for everybody.
My recommendation is that you don't use C library collations, but ICU collations. The ICU library offers an "undefined" collation that is supposed to be a middle ground that works good enough for everybody. If you are using PostgreSQL v15 or later, and your PostgreSQL was built with ICU support, you could create your database with
CREATE DATABASE all_languages
   TEMPLATE template0
   ENCODING UTF8
   LOCALE_PROVIDER icu
   ICU_LOCALE und
   LOCALE "en_US";

The C library locale you still have to specify is used for other locale aspects than collation.
